# Compare properties from different classes in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have two classes, A and B.

```
class A {
  id: number;
}

class B {
  id: number;
}
```

Is it possible to have a function typed so that it only accepts id from class A? Maybe by changing `number` to a custom type of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `id` property of class `A` to be of a [*nominal type*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) compatible with `number`. If this type is declared as `ClassANumber`, it would be considered distinct from a regular `number` type, because they have different declarations and different names.  So your ideal behavior might look like this:

```
class A {
  id: ClassANumber;
  constructor(id: ClassANumber) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

class B {
  id: number;
  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}

function acceptClassAId(id: ClassANumber) { }
acceptClassAId(new A(1).id) // okay
acceptClassAId(new B(1).id) // error, number is not a ClassANumber
```

---

Unfortunately, TypeScript's type system is [*structural*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system), and not nominal.  If the types `number` and `ClassANumber` have the same structure (that is, they both behave like a `number` when used), then the compiler will consider them the same type:

```
type ClassANumber = number;

acceptClassAId(new A(1).id) // no error, as desired
acceptClassAId(new B(1).id) // ALSO no error,
```

There is no error here because `ClassANumber` is the same type as `number`, and so `new B(1).id`'s type, `number`, is assignable to `ClassANumber`.

---

There are various tricks you can use to simulate nominal types in TypeScript; you can see [the Nominal Typing section of @basarat's TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping), or [the TypeScript FAQ entry for "Can I make a type alias nominal"?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).  The canonical place to discuss/consider/lament this is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202), an open issue since 2014.

The one I'll present here is from the "Can I make a type alias nominal" FAQ entry.  It uses so-called *type branding* to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) the `number` primitive with an object type containing a single property which can be used to distinguish `number` from `ClassANumber`:

```
type ClassANumber = number & { __classAId: true };
```

Now the compiler can tell the difference:

```
acceptClassAId(new A(1).id) // okay
acceptClassAId(new B(1).id) // error!
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassANumber'.
```

This is just a workaround, of course.  Technically you're lying to the compiler: at runtime, a `ClassANumber` will just be a `number`, without a `__classAId` property.  And so there are various warts that crop up at compile time.  For example, since there's no way to turn a `number` into a `ClassANumber` for real,  you'll have to use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in any code that needs to do this:

```
class A {
  id: ClassANumber;
  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id as ClassANumber; // need to assert here
  }
}
```

And once you do have something the compiler believes is a `ClassANumber`, you'll see this phantom `__classAId` property you need to steer clear of:

```
new A(2).id.__classAId.valueOf(); // accepted by compiler, but error at runtime
```

So proceed with caution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgPID2MUAghhgMoAuATgK7zseZ76EiSFgE8YyAMIYQUegDkOYAEYQ2SALzFFKtgG4BQpPGmykdfoaIBLACYAuJFJnztq-ZaNVgUHtypsAClsHJ1k6BWVVAEoLD2EACysoADpbDSRbd0sAX0EiXLyjEygkACFYw2CtSL1CongvH04-QKrgVzYYgjiEpNSbdMy6pALDXMMAMw5gbisvJAREGBZQ+gBJGyD7R2Lwjq6RgyFFiGXVug2A4AgAdzMAgEYo-piAelfiKiRVNn8AGgWJRs0CsbAgNkKJzOu0u1zupUez1sbw+dAAMkwKJ9vmxfmwAYBeDcARHsCQSjYjgaBwRBIORUMBWUAYJLxCrCMSSXYRHTpdo1JAAMjwSAA+iLjM4LtseMhsvpChLTOZupYquduW5hg1vL4WP4tg4+TousMiCxEik0po0jIdpKNXokO9iBBwcIvs5VCwkPFVBBhuMhOT6sUymzrNsjZqPNqmlw9a1I-tw0JzX0rRkbFkxkd8oUpjMWHNgAt4EsVjDNmqucncIdIWXThXJbDbvcni8nR8qABrEAiBvl86t+GIzvOn7+ACEhWddDYAHNFBBgN6qBN2eIkAByKNsbcZErAKje5xWBegJQYZB6pBwNiUliqJDrzfIbfqjrb5Kkwxw+4AExIjYyRioq6wgQAbpgHAQBQEwBFEuhdqW5ZukoIieGAMBWNe+JIEoHDepOaggN6nCrlYkBHLk2RAA)